# Sound card vanished from sound settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

For no apparent reason the sound card is no longer visible in sound settings. Even dummy device is gone. Unsurprisingly flash produces no sound. The sound card is working as the system sounds are still active although sound test does nothing.

What is the problem and how do I fix it (idally without restating)

I have tried `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` which has been a faithful fixer of sound problems in the past but this was not the case this time.

I followed instructions on restarting pulseaudio (I must confess I was not really clear what I was doing or why so I was probably just wasting time) this has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to reset pulseaudio configuration :
  `rm -fr .pulse`
  then reboot.
- If not better , what is this 2 commands results:
  `pactl info|grep sink`
  and
  `aplay -l`
- Do you see faders running alsamixer in a terminal ? Are main faders (master, pcm, speakers... )  unmuted  (<kbd>m</kbd> key to mute/unmute when fader selected with arrow key)?